# useQuery causes Infinite loop in Next.js

Tags: next.js, react-query

_app

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
      queries: { staleTime: Infinity, retry: 0, suspense: true },
    },
  })
```

index.tsx

```
const { data: categories } = useQuery<categories[]>(['categories'], () =>
    fetch(`${server}/api/get-categories`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => data.items),
  )
```

[image]

I'd like to use suspense in next.js.
But as soon as I add `suspense: true` at queryClient in _app, fetch causes infinite loop..
Why did this happen?